# Query on Static member variables of a class

Tags: c++

I have few classes defined in this fashion :

```
class CSocket {
    protected:
        int m_SockWorking;
        int InitSocket();
        void CleanSocket();
}

class CSocketClient : public CSocket {
    public:
        CSocketClient();
        int InitClient();
}

class CApi {
    static CSocketClient c1;
    public:
        // other methods defined 
}
```

Now, in the main routine I create two objects of class `CApi`. I know that for static member variables there exists only one copy per class. But, how can I access `m_SockWorking` variable for `CSocketClient` member variable? Will there be two copies of that non static member variable for the two objects? Can somebody please explain?

Comment: there will be one copy of `m_SockWorking` for two and more `CApi ` objects

Comment: Please add your main routine. From which part of the code are you trying to access m_SockWorking variable (data member)?

Comment: Why do you think there would be two copies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `CApi` classes will share a single static `CSocketClient` variable.

`m_SockWorking` is a protected member of `CSocket` which is inheirited by `CSocketClient` this makes it a private variable inside the context of `CApi` and your application. So you can access it through the use of accessor and mutator functions.

Each `CSocketClient` has its own `m_SockWorking` variable. Since all `CApi` all share the same `CSocketClient` class, they all share the same `m_SockWorking` variable.

**CSocket.h**

```
class CSocket {
  protected:
    int m_SockWorking;
    int InitSocket();
    void CleanSocket();
  public:
    void setSocket(int val){ m_SockWorking = val; } /* added these functions to show how to accessing m_SockWorking can be done */
    int getSocket() const { return m_SockWorking; }
};

class CSocketClient : public CSocket {
  public:
    CSocketClient();
    int InitClient();

};

class CApi {
  static CSocketClient c1;
  public:
    // other methods defined 
};
```

**main.cc**

```
#include "CSocket.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){
  CApi a, b;
  CSocketClient c2;
  a.c1.setSocket(0); /* sets static c1 m_SockWorking variable to 0 */
  cout << b.c1.getSocket() << endl; /* will print 0 since c1 is a static variable */
  c2.setSocket(1); /* set c2 m_SockWorking to 1 */
  cout << c2.getSocket() << endl; /* will print 1 */
  cout << a.c1.getSocket() << endl; /* will print 0 */
}
```

**Output**

```
0
1
1
```

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, object c1 is unique, so, all data members within to c1 are unique for CApi.

Maybe it's less confusing in this way:

static object c1 is a standalone & unique object for the "CLASS" CApi, accessible by objects of CApi. It belongs to the class, NOT to any objects of CApi; it's NOT A SHARED PART of objects of CApi.